# Find corner points of eyes and Mouth

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab, matlab-cvst

I am able to detect eyes, nose and mouth in a given face using Matlab. Now, I want four more points i.e corners of the eyes and nose. how do i get these points??

This is the Image for corner points of nose.

[image: Corner Points of nose]

Red point is showing the point, what I'm looking for.(its just to let you know.. there is no point in original image)

Comment: Could you post a clean image with the eyes and the nose in it (so we have got something to work with) and then another image where you highlight expected result (e.g drawing them in paint manually), please?

Comment: I would just use Face++, they have an sdk in Matlab:
http://www.faceplusplus.com/

Answer (score 1):

Active Appearance Model (AAM) could be useful in your case.

AMM is normally used for matching a statistical model of object shape and appearance to a new image and widely used for extracting face features and for head pose estimation.

I believe [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32704-icaam-inverse-compositional-active-appearance-models) could be helpful for you to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using corner detectors included in the computer vision system toolbox, such as `detectHarrisFeatures`, `detectMinEigenFeatures`, or `detectFASTFeatures`. However they may give you more points than you want, so you will have to do some parameter tweaking.